# Replacement for enumerateSubstringsInRange in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, string, foundation

I'm upgrading code from Swift 2 to Swift 3 and ran across this error:

> wordcount.swift:7:5: error: value of type 'String' has no member 'enumerateSubstringsInRange'
>      line.enumerateSubstringsInRange(range, options: .ByWords) {w,*,*,_ in

In Swift 2, this method comes from a `String` extension of which the compiler is aware.

I have not been able to locate this method in the Swift 3 library. It appears in the documentation for `Foundation` here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:

My entire script is:

```
import Foundation

var counts = [String: Int]()

while let line = readLine()?.lowercased() {
    let range = line.characters.indices
    line.enumerateSubstringsInRange(range, options: .ByWords) {w,_,_,_ in
        guard let word = w else {return}
        counts[word] = (counts[word] ?? 0) + 1
    }
}

for (word, count) in (counts.sorted {$0.0 < $1.0}) {
    print("\(word) \(count)")
}
```

It works with Swift 2.2 (modulo the changes I have *already* made for Swift 3, such as `lowercase` -> `lowercased` and `sort` -> `sorted`) but fails to compile with Swift 3.

And very strangely, neither the Swift 3 command line compiler nor the Swift Migration assistant in XCode 8 Beta suggests a replacement, as it does for many other renamed methods. Perhaps `enumerateSubstringsInRange` is deprecated or its parameter names changed?

Comment: It got changed to `enumerateSubstrings(in: range, options: .ByWords) {}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you type `str.enumerateSubstrings` in a Playground, you'll see the following as a completion option:

```
enumerateSubstrings(in: Range<Index>, options: EnumerationOptions, body: (substring: String?, substringRange: Range<Index>, enclosingRange: Range<Index>, inout Bool) -> ())
```

---

In addition to addressing the new `enumerateSubstrings(in:options:body:)` syntax, you need to also change how you get the `range` for the string:

```
import Foundation

var counts = [String: Int]()

while let line = readLine()?.lowercased() {
    let range = line.startIndex ..< line.endIndex
    line.enumerateSubstrings(in: range, options: .byWords) {w,_,_,_ in
        guard let word = w else {return}
        counts[word] = (counts[word] ?? 0) + 1
    }
}

for (word, count) in (counts.sorted {$0.0 < $1.0}) {
    print("\(word) \(count)")
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. I should have guessed that was the new method, given that I've seen many fixes such as `joinWithSeparator(_:)` becoming `joined(separator:)`.

Comment: Why does it have to be so complicated? Shouldn't it be easier than Obj-C, where you simply use `NSMakeRange(0, line.length)`?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei, I share your frustration.  The designers of Swift have made Strings more capable than before, but working with them is a bit more difficult at times.